What are the Śaiva explanations for "saṅkarṣaṇamūrtisvarūpo (सङ्कर्षणमूर्तिस्वरूपो)" in the chamakam of Śrī Rudram and the source of this mantra?
This is the mantra:
अस्य श्री रुद्राध्याय प्रश्न महामन्त्रस्य अघोर ऋषिः अनुष्टुप् छन्दः सङ्कर्षणमूर्तिस्वरूपो योऽसावादित्यः परमपुरुषः स एष रुद्रो देवता ।
